# Alguien sabe como puedo solucionar el error 424 que me aparece al intentar abrir un formulario? No es ningún nombre mal escrito ni nada por el estilo

Tags: excel, vba

'Este es el trozo de código que me da problemas, desde que lo he añadido no me deja abrir el formulario por error 424.

```
    For i = 0 To i = 7
        If ActiveCell.Value = d Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            For j = 0 To j = 12
                If ActiveCell.Value = CB_Operari.Value Then
                    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
                    ActiveCell.Value = TXTNomFeina.Value
                    Exit For
                End If
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            Next j
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Next i
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el mensaje de error?

Comment: debajo del `ActiveCell.Value = TXTNomFeina.Value` creo que primero debe ir `End If` y luego `Exit For`

Comment: un bucle for con variable se escribiría `For i= to 7`, no como lo tienes escrito tú

Comment: El depurador debe indicar la linea del error, esto si das clic en depurar cuando sale el mensaje, ¿en cual linea te da el error?, por otro lado, los ciclos `For` no estan bien definidos, si quieres que el primer ciclo inicie en cero y termine en 7, entonces deberías definirlo asi: `For i = 0 To 7`, en el caso del segundo, debería ser asi: `For j = 0 To 12`, asi como esta, cada ciclo se ejecutara solo una vez.

Answer (score 0):

lo primero que estoy observando es que los bucles For yo lo iniciaria de la siguiente manera:
for i= 0 to 7
for j= o to 12
En el caso del Exti For esta bien ubicado por que es una de las formas de salir de un bucle, en esta pagina hay un par de ejemplos
https://excelyvba.com/el-bucle-for-next/
Epero que sirva de algo
Saludos
MC